# Adding edge labels to a CSS based tree

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is based on [this](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree).

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/danyaljj/sq6wy6bq/

[image]

I want to add labels on the edges. Any idea what is the best way to do this? (the set of the possible labels is limited, like 10 labels). Something like this: 
[image]

Comment: Since you are already heavily making use of ::after and ::before pseudo elements, I'd say bad luck. Don't think this is possible within the frameset of the current solution.

Comment: Just make use of new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution far from robust that will only allow a label on first and last item of your 3-items list (there's no phydical place for a label on second one...)

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sq6wy6bq/2/

HTML code: I'd add the *label* in each item before the labelled child so:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="so-label">Label 1</span>
        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="so-label">Label 2</span>
        <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Relevant CSS: yay absolute positioning (sigh)

```
.so-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: -40%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
li:first-child .so-label {
    left: 50%;
}
li:last-child .so-label {
    left: -50%;
}
```

In case of 2 or 4-10 children (wow), you can still know the number of items in the list and position by hand each label: [trick from André Luís](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/). Labels that should not be too long or it'll surimpose...

Possible improvements:

- flexbox or CSS table layout can achieve a correct visual display of a row of labels but then those labels would decorrelated of their respective items (children) and that would lead to bad semantics. Improving this semantics by associating back labels and items could be achieved via WAI-ARIA (`aria-describedby` or similar ARIA attributes)
- Or you could use ([accessible](http://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/)) **SVG** :) Graphs love SVG!

Comment: Any idea how to makes edges directed?

Comment: You mean having a triangle pointing downwards and located probably at the end of the edge (touching its child), less probably right in the middle of the edge and not writing 'Label 1' from right to left?

Comment: yeah a triangle on the edge which shows the direction. Not sure if this is feasible with the current CSS-based definition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215783/adding-directed-edges-to-a-css-based-graph-visualizer