# Adding directed edges to a CSS-based graph visualizer

Tags: html, css

See [this](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) CSS-based visualization for graphs. Any idea what is the easiest way to add directions to edges (e.g. arrows on edges)?

Comment: Your javascript tag is really not accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `<li>` contents with `<span>` tags and style the pseudo elements to achieve a proper result. You may not use ASCII characters, backgounds or even pure CSS triangles.

http://jsfiddle.net/ndozdw00/1/

```
.tree li span:after{
  content: "▼";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```